# C++ Change Default accent color using winapi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I was wondering how to change the accent color in C++, can anyone provide me some code. I did some investigating but I couldn't find anything. If somebody doesn't know what I'm talking about , [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCmkt.png) is a imgur link showing what setting I'm trying to change.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

If anyone does not know what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm trying to change the accent color setting using the API.

Comment: These settings are for the user to change, which is why you won't find an api for it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To be fair, Microsoft does not really document how to *get* the color either in desktop apps. In fact, Microsoft has been sloppy since the start of Vista and the lack of DWM related color queries. Dark mode is also still fully undocumented for desktop apps...